# Xcode error: Comparison between pointer and integer?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting this error on my if statement.

**CODE:**

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{

    NSString *correctUser = @"money";
    NSString *correctPassword = @"ilovemoney";

    if ((usernameTextField.text == correctUser)==YES && (passwordTextField.text = correctPassword)==YES) //error is on the beginning of this if statement.
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"oneTransition" sender:sender];
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the types of `usernameTextField.text` and `YES`?

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch of problems here.

- You're using `=` instead of `==` in your second test, which is assignment, not comparison; this is why you're getting the warning.
- Comparing strings with `==` doesn't do what you want. You should use `[usernameTextField.text isEqual:correctUser]`, for example.
- You should [never compare something to YES](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/) as in `== YES`. So, instead of `if (something == YES)` just say `if (something)`.

Comment: On that third point, you should always use `if( ((((a == b) == YES) == YES) == YES) == YES )`. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Yes, thanks, @Dave, I had forgotten to mention that.

Comment: Thanks. that worked, I used the isEqual.